# Lanes between circles in tds

Tags: html, css, sass

How do i put lanes between these circles, i've been googling it but I dont see the easiest way to do it,

```css
.table_1 {
  tr {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
    line-height: 30px;
    td:nth-child(2) {
      vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    td:nth-child(1) {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-right: 28px;
      width: 42px;
      height: 42px;
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid #999999;
      border-radius: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 31%;
      span {
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: #999999;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 32px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

edit...
i want to connect all the circles by lines something like

```
    1
    |
    2  
    |
    3
```

and so on

https://jsfiddle.net/cfmorales/hutpvac5/1/

Comment: You're going to need to describe what "Lanes between circles" actually means.

Comment: Please edit your questions to put the code from the fiddle into a stack snippet.

Comment: He can't, it uses sass.

Comment: Whatever this is supposed to represent, it should probably not be build using table markup to begin with.

Comment: @DBS just edited, srry :c

Comment: @04FS yeah, the thing is I cant change the html, it's generated by the server I'm just able to play with the css, is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can use background https://jsfiddle.net/yncx2hz8/

Comment: Try this: `td {position: relative;}` and `td::after {
    content: "";
    bottom: -26px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 60%;
    background: #999;
}`. Pleas let me know if it worked for you. Of course you would probably want to play with direction and height to adjust it for your needs.

Comment: transform and border could be used too https://jsfiddle.net/d6m8Lejg/

Comment: I wouldn't go with table element, but divs that have display:flex, flex-direction column, and just have a div that has width: 1px and height that u need, between circle divs, it is the easiest solution imo. @Christian

Comment: @NemanjaG as long as you do not really know what goes inside the table aside the first column, it is hard to say : this is not a table , it might only be a sample of its code showing only the issue part ;) Is it a time line or something else, should it be a list or title and paragrphes aside ..

Comment: @G-Cyr you can create a structure that is table-like with divs, and it is easier to handle these css things, just an opinion, you can use table but this might be simpler.

Comment: @NemanjaG it did  hitches me to also give my opinion about the code, what is that table doing here ? ;)

Comment: thank u guys I just got so many ways to do it @ g-Cyr, and @ konrud

Comment: @JeremyHarris the SCSS can be compiled for the stack snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ? The css is commented

```css
tr {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

td {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 28px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 31%;

  /* making the element relative to position the lane relative to it */
  position: relative;
}


/* Selecting all td except the last one and using pseudo-class :after to shape the lane */

tr:not(:last-child)>td:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 4px;
  top: 110%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="table_1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>4</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>5</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
```

Comment: the lane in te :before isnt responsive, if the page is open in desktops of diferent resolution the lanes doesnt connect to the circles, any way to fix it?

Comment: I just used random values for the demonstrations, if you want the lanes to connect from the bottom edge of the circle to the top edge of circle below it, set `top:100%; height: 62%;`

Comment: it doesnt work :'c look this is my code, if u have more content the lines doesnt match https://codepen.io/cfmorales/pen/dyPOEBd

Comment: You didn't mention any of that in your question, the main problem was to have lanes below circles, the `codepen` you just shared is a lot different, here the text is the one that controls the height not the td with the circles, Here's a workaround that needs to be maintained if the size of the circle changes [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfg8q54s/)

Comment: i love you dude I need to learn about those calc values, thanks

Comment: @Christian nothing complicated.just subtracting additional pixels from their respective places

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with "divs", and use some css with "nth-child"

```css
   div:nth-child(2n+1) {

  background: red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

div:nth-child(2n) {
  background: blue;
  width:2px;
  margin-left:24px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div></div>
<div>1</div>
<div></div>
<div>1</div>
<div></div>
<div>1</div>
<div></div>
<div>1</div>
```